# Is there a way to call action from beforeAction()?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Is there a way to dynamically call  an arbitrary action from beforeAction() method in Yii2?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I need it for multistep forms

Comment: Fair enough, Double H's answer below will allow you to do this, just remember that if you're using that function within a controller, and you call another action within that controller, the beforeAction function will be called again, and you may end up with a loop situation

Answer (score 1):

Override BeforeAction Event in your Controller

```
public function beforeAction($action){

    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do??

Comment: I need to call  another action not the one which should be processed.

Comment: I need to do it without redirecting browser.

Comment: though I knew about it and I just wanted to know is there another way, I think I will stick with redirect

Comment: Having it work without redirect is bad practice, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling action inside of `beforeAction()`, configuring response and returning `false` - it will prevent of executing requested action.

```
public function beforeAction($action){
    if ($this->someCondition()) {
        $response = $this->actionMySecondAction();
        if (!$response instanceof \yii\web\Response) {
            Yii::$app->response->data = $response;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

But this is kind of hack and you may experience some weird side effects. You should really reconsider your architecture to avoid such solutions. If you have multi step form you may use one URL and one action - split steps to separate methods and call required method depending on form status, not URL. No need to use such hacks and you will avoid displaying second step at `http://localhost/form/third-step`.

Answer (score -1):

If you'll not finish the app in beforeAction it will continue to the action and execute redirect **only after return inside of the action**.

To avoid this behaviour you should end the app inside the beforeAction method and don't use return with redirect:

```
public function beforeAction($action){

    if ($some_conditions && $this->getRoute() != 'site/index') {
        $this->redirect(['site/index']);
        Yii::$app->end();
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: It does not make any sense - `Yii::$app->end();` will never be reached since it is after `return` statement.

Comment: @rob006 Sorry, it's a typo. Fixed it.